# setMap(null) not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

im trying to delete a Marker from a Map via ajax request.

ajax request looks like this.

```
    $(document).on('click','.deletebtn',function(){

        var theid =$(this).parent().attr("id");
          var obj = {
              id:theid
          }
          $.ajax({
              url:"http://localhost:3000/singleMarker",
              method:"post",
              contentType:"application/json",
              data:JSON.stringify(obj),
              dataType:"JSON",
              processData: true,
              success:function(responseData){
                  clearMarker(responseData);
              }
          });

    });
```

the response will reply with a single obj {id:id, {lat:xxx,lng:yyy}}

next i turn the lat lng data into a marker obj:

```
    var clearMarker = function(responseData){
    //clearAll Markers from Map
    var markers =[];
    var temp ={};
    var marker;
    for(var key in responseData){
        //create markers with latlng objs
        temp ={lat:responseData[key].pos.lat,lng:responseData[key].pos.lng};
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:temp,
            map:meineMap
        });
        markers.push(marker);
    }
    setMapOnAll(null,markers);
}
```

then setMapOnAll with map  null should delete all markers from the map but is not doing so. why?

```
function setMapOnAll(map,markers) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
    //markers[i].setVisible(false);

  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating markers in your `clearMarker` function?  You want to act on the **existing** markers.

Answer (score 0):

If you only ever have one marker, there is no need to maintain an array of markers (or to call `setMapOnAll`), move the `marker` declaration out of the `clearMarker` function, if the marker exists, set its `map` property to `null`, otherwise, it is the first marker, just create it.

```
var marker;
var clearMarker = function(responseData){
    //clearAll Markers from Map
    var temp ={};

    for(var key in responseData){
        //create markers with latlng objs
        temp ={lat:responseData[key].pos.lat,lng:responseData[key].pos.lng};
        if (marker && marker.setMap) marker.setMap(null);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:temp,
            map:meineMap
        });
    }
}
```